# Java - when to use 'this' keyword

Tags: java, coding-style, this

What is the best practise for using the `this` keyword in Java? For example, I have the following class:

```
class Foo {
    Bar bar;

    public Foo(Bar bar) {
         this.bar = bar;
    }
}
```

That's fine and all, but Java is clever enough to know what is happening if I change the statement in the constructor to

```
 bar = bar;
```

So why use the `this` keyword? (I realise in some situations, it's totally necessary to use it, I'm just asking for situations like this). Actually, I tend to use the keyword purely for readability sake but what's the common practise? Using it all over the shop makes my code look a bit messy, for example

```
boolean baz;
int someIndex = 5;
this.baz = this.bar.getSomeNumber() == this.someBarArray[this.someIndex].getSomeNumber();
```

Obviously a poor bit of code but it illustrates my example. Is it just down to personal preference in these cases?

Comment: The same question was posted 2 days ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2411270/when-should-i-use-this-in-a-class There are by the way more dupes: http://www.google.com/search?q=java+when+use+this+keyword+site%3Astackoverflow.com

Comment: My bad, I had a (clearly very) quick search using the SO search but didn't find anything...

Comment: As others have pointed out, you're doing assignment to self (parameter) above. But my rule of thumb is to use `this` when it makes the program more *readable*. If you use some kind of naming convention for member variables (e.g. `_bar` or `mBar`), then writing `this._bar` is just extra noise, IMHO.

Comment: The real question (for me) is why on earth do people use the same name for method parameters and member variables?  I can't stand this practice, as it does nothing but introduce an opportunity for confusion.  Unfortunately (for me) this is very popular and most frameworks that automatically generate code do it :/  Grr...

Comment: If you don't use same identifier in local variables, the `this` can be omitted in your first case. And, as for other cases, I think correctness along with readability is beauty.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

> but Java is clever enough to know what is happening if I change the statement in the constructor to
>
> ```
>   bar = bar;
> ```

FALSE! It compiles but it doesn't do what you think it does!

As to when to use it, a lot of it is personal preference. I like to use `this` in my public methods, even when it's unnecessary, because that's where the interfacing happens and it's nice to assert what's mine and what's not.

As reference, you can check the Oracle's Java Tutorials out about this.subject ;-)

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html

Comment: Thats why I like to mark all parameter variables as final.

Comment: yeah it just reassigns the variable bar in the contructor to itself. This is because bar is already defined in the scope and it overides the one from Bar bar.

Answer (score 23):

You should use it when you have a parameter with the same name as a field otherwise you will run into issues. It will compile, but won't necessarily do what you want it to.

As for everywhere else, don't use it unless it's needed for readability's sake. If you use it everywhere, 20% of your code will consist of the word 'this'!

Comment: Though it's arguable that the explicit `this` keyword everywhere can be helpful. Languages like Python and Rust require it in fact (`self`), and I've never seen this explicitness as a negative.

Comment: Brilliant answer, short, concise, to the point

Comment: I have seen many people use `this` all over their code and I mostly find it annoying. In general, I don't like adding extra characters to my code when they aren't specifically doing anything. Am I wrong to believe this?

Comment: Another instance of this is the use of the word `final` everywhere. I got into a kick for a while where I added it everywhere I possibly could and it frustrated other developers. Eventually I stopped and only added it where required (lambdas require fields to be final or effectively immutable).

I kind of wish Java would make local variables `final` by default and require the use of `var` or something like that for variables that are NOT immutable.

Answer (score 12):

Actually

```
baz = baz
```

will raise this warning

> The assignment to variable baz has no
>   effect

So what you think is wrong, the local scope overrides the class attribute so you **MUST** use `this` keyword explictly to assign the variable to the class attribute.

Otherwise the variable accounted into assignment is just the one passed as a parameter and the class one is ignored. That's why `this` is useful, it's not a fact of readability, it's a fact of explicitly deciding which `baz` are you talking about.

I would say

> use `this` wherever not using it would cause ambiguities (or compiler warning, that are more important), otherwise just leave it. Since its purpose is exactly to solve ambiguities when default assumptions (first check locals, then check class attributes) are not enough.

Answer (score 11):

`this` keyword refers to the Object of class on which some method is invoked.
For example:

```
public class Xyz {  
    public Xyz(Abc ob)
    {
        ob.show();
    }
}

public class Abc {
    int a = 10;

    public Abc()
    {
        new Xyz(this);
    }

    public void show()
    {
        System.out.println("Value of a " + a);
    }

    public static void main(String s[])
    {
        new Abc();
    }
}
```

Here in `Abc()` we are calling `Xyz()` which needs Object of Abc Class.. So we can pass `this` instead of new `Abc()`, because if we pass new `Abc()` here it will call itself again and again.

Also we use this to differentiate variables of class and local variables of method. e.g

```
class Abc {
    int a;

    void setValue(int a)
    {
        this.a = a;
    }
}
```

Here `this.a` is refers to variable a of class Abc. Hence having same effect as you use new `Abc().a;`.

So you can say `this` refers to object of current class.

Answer (score 7):

It is common to use **this** keyword in ***explicit constructor invocation***. You can see an example from the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html).

```
public class Rectangle {
    private int x, y;
    private int width, height;

    public Rectangle() {
        this(0, 0, 1, 1);
    }
    public Rectangle(int width, int height) {
        this(0, 0, width, height);
    }
    public Rectangle(int x, int y, int width, int height) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
public Foo(Bar bar) {
     this.bar = bar;
}
```

is not the same as

```
public Foo(Bar bar) {
     bar = bar;
}
```

In the second case the bar in scope is the parameter, so you assign it to itself. `this.bar` remains `null`.

Answer (score 4):

Depending on convention, you can use it for readability. It stresses the fact that it's an object variable.

I also like to have setter arguments with the same name as the variable (looks better in method signature). You need `this` in this case.

Answer (score 3):

It is a personal preference - choose a style and stick to it.  I personally use `this` but others think it is redundant.

Answer (score 2):

Personal preference, but I use it to solve ambiguities only, and I suppose in the very rare case to make it obvious that the assigned variable is a field.  There are some projects where people use "this.field" on every single field reference.  I find this practice visually distracting to the point of being obnoxious, but you should be prepared to see such code once in a while.

I secretly think there's a special place in hell for people who write 500 line classes that have 275 'this' keywords in them, but this style is found in some open source projects, so to each his own I guess.

Comment: +1 If find using this.* everywhere very annoying.If you're using a modern IDE, and design classes properly, you'll never run into a situation where you have to figure out what the refered to variable is (attribute, local variable etc.)

Answer (score 2):

I always try to use `this` keyword on local class objects.

I use it to visually remind me if an object is static object or class object.

It helps me and the compiler differentiate between method args and local class object.

```
public void setValue(int value){
  this.value = value;
}
```

It helps me to visually remind me if there is such a local object in an inner/nested/anonymous class to differentiate it from encapsulating class objects. Because if there is not `this` prefixed, my convention will remind me that it is an object of the encapsulating class

```
public class Hello{
  public int value = 0;
  public boolean modal = false;

  public class Hellee{
    public int value = 1;
    public getValue(){
      if (modal)
        return 0;
      return this.value;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
void set(int real)
{
    this.real = real;
}
```

here `this` is a keyword used when there is instance variable is same as the local variable.
another use of `this` is constructor overloading. it can call the constructor in a overloaded constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Use it for Cloning objects (by passing reference of itself through a copy constructor).

Useful for object that inherits `Cloneable`.

```
public Foo implements Cloneable {
  private String bar;

  public Foo(Foo who) {
    bar = who.bar;
  }

  public Object getClone() {
    return new Foo(this);  //Return new copy of self.
  }
}
```