# ListView empty if SimpleCursorAdapter closed()

Tags: android, android-listview, simplecursoradapter

I have a problem understanding why is my ListActivity and its corresponding *listView* empty when I call **close()** method on *cursor* object?

Let me explain myself a bit...

I retreive some values from a DB and get the result in my cursor object. After that I create my *SimpleCursorAdapter* and bind column from db with a field in my *listView*.

Works like a charm, but...

If I call **cursor.close()** at the end of *onCreate()* method my listView is shown empty?

If I log the values from cursor to LogCat they're there until calling *cursor.close()* and that makes perfect sense, but why is the listAdapter emptied when *cursor.close()* is called???
I would expect *ListAdapter listAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(...)* to hold the values that are "binded" to a *listView* until we activity is destroyed...

Why is this so? When and why is necessary to close cursor?

```
public class ListTrainingsView extends ListActivity{
private SQLiteDatabase db;
private ListAdapter  listAdapter;
private Cursor cursor;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.list_trainings);

    DatabaseHelper helper = new DatabaseHelper(this);

    this.db = helper.getWritableDatabase();

    this.cursor = db.query("trainings", fields, null, null, null, null, null);

    startManagingCursor(cursor);

    this.listAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
            R.layout.list_trainings_item, 
            cursor, 
            new String[] {"name"},
            new int[] { R.id.name_entry}
    );

    this.setListAdapter(this.listAdapter);

//If I call 
//cursor.close();
//shown list is empty
```

Another question is more of basic Java language type of question... I come from PHP OO background and there if you define member variable you have to work with it in object methods using syntax *$this->cursor*. I've noticed that in Android/Java I don't have to use *this.cursor.getCount()* to get the reference/value from it. It's enough to say *cursor.getCount()* How come this is allowed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is this so?

`Adapter` needs data from provided `Cursor` and prepare `ListView` accordingly, and when you call `cursor.close()` the `Cursor` is released and made invalid. (means there is no data.)

> When and why is necessary to close cursor?

It is necessary to close the `Cursor` while you are about to leave the `Activity` and going back from the `Activity` otherwise `Cursor` got leaked for that `Activity`.

- References From [**documentation**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#close%28%29)
- Any why it is [**necessary**](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/8cc32515a0ce5994?pli=1)

> It's enough to say cursor.getCount() How come this is allowed?

The structure of Java is based on classes. Every action is done within a specific class. Even echoing "**single line**" would need a class. and when you are in a class you can access class members with `this` **OR** with direct their variables

- For more see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2429062/java-when-to-use-this-keyword)

Answer (score 2):

You should not close your cursor unil your Activity is destroyed (i.e. in `onDestroy()`) because the implementation of CursorAdapter expects it to be open to be able to requery and filter it.

Since you're calling `startManagingCursor` anyway, your Activity will automatically deactivite, requery and close the cursor upon the appropriate Activity lifecycle events, so there is no need to close it yourself.