# No dataType in variable declaration

Tags: java, variables

[Java documentation says](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/variables.html)

> ### Field declarations are composed of three components, in order:
>
> 1. Zero or more modifiers, such as public or private.
> 2. The field's type.
> 3. The field's name.

however, variable declaration in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15825683/3916149) post has confused me.

```
private final firstName;
private final lastName;
```

I cannot understand why there is no dataType for first two variables declared?

Whereas, 3rd and 4th has?

```
private final Date birthdate;
private final Address address;
```

Note:Am learning Java, hence to understand if am missing on anything related to variable declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That post is incorrect, it should be:

```
private final String firstName;
private final String lastName;
```

Answer (score 0):

It because he made a mistake forgetting to place a data type on those variable. So it should look like this:

```
private final String firstName;
private final String lastName;
```