# java "this" keyword proper use

Tags: java, this

I have a Fraction class using keyword    this in my constructor:

```
public Fraction(int numerator, int denominator)
{
    this.numerator = numerator; 
    this.denominator = denominator; 
    adjustSigns();

    if(this.denominator == 0 )
    {
     throw new FractionException(" Undefined Fraction ");
    } 
}
```

I also have a method :

```
 public FractionInterface multiply(FractionInterface secondFraction)
 {
    Fraction second = (Fraction) secondFraction; 
    Fraction answer = new Fraction ((numerator * second.numerator), (denominator * second.denominator));        
    answer.reduceToLowestTerms();
    return answer; 
}
```

The above method works fine when I compile and run but so this this version:

```
 public FractionInterface multiply(FractionInterface secondFraction)
 {
    Fraction second = (Fraction) secondFraction; 
    Fraction answer = new Fraction ((this.numerator * second.numerator), (this.denominator * second.denominator));      
    answer.reduceToLowestTerms();
    return answer; 
 }
```

My question is which one is correct ?? If use the "this" keyword in my constructor do I also have to use it in my methods ?? Again, they both work fine and do what they are supposed to do but I want to know which way is the correct way. Thanks.

Comment: the use of `this` in the constructor (or setters) is usually used to disambiguate the variable names

Comment: In terms of `this`, both are correct. The bigger issue with both `multiply` implementations is that they **lie**: They claim to accept anything implementing the `FractionInterface`, but in fact they only accept instances of `Fraction` and `Fraction` subclasses. A correct implementation would work with `FractionInterface` (or declare the argument of type `Fraction` instead).

Comment: But on `this`: There are two schools of thought on using `this` on the occasions it's optional: The school who feel that since it's not necessary, it's just extra typing/text, and the school who feel that it's useful for clarity. If you don't use `this`, it's easy to think that `numerator` is a function argument or local variable rather than an instance field.

Comment: Consider this example for more http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2429062/java-when-to-use-this-keyword

Comment: You should aim to eliminate redundant notation wherever encountered.

Answer (score 4):

Using `this` explicitly is mandatory if you wish to distinguish between a local variable and a member of the same name. Otherwise, it is optional.

Your constructor won't assign the passes values to the instance members without the `this.` prefix, since the method arguments would hide the instance members. If you give the arguments different names, you can do without the `this.` :

```
public Fraction(int num, int denom)
{
    numerator = num; 
    denominator = denom;
    ...
}
```

Both `multiply` versions are the same.

Comment: E.g., both `multiply` method implementations are "correct" (other than that cast!).

Comment: why is the cast incorrect ?? according to my professor I had to  downcast reference parameter FractionInterface to Fraction if  I want to use it as Fraction.

Comment: @lrod408 The cast has the potential of throwing ClassCastException, since you don't verify that `secondFraction` is an `instanceof Fraction` before casting it. If multiple classes implement `FractionInterface`, the cast would fail for some of them.

Comment: @T.J Crowder, thanks for the heads up. This time only the `Fraction` class implements `FractionInterFace` but that is still good to know. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 2):

Both the cases you mentioned will work fine.

Use of `this` is a good practice as its more readable due to our english mindset, When we say `this.some_variable`, we get a mental image of some_variable inside the current class

`this` keyword is also helpful in avoiding variable shadowing

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a bit of a confusion on how the "this" keyword works.

Let me give you an example:

This

```
public class testing {
    private int a;
    private int b;

    testing(int a,int b){
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }
}
```

is the same as:

```
public class testing {
    private int a;
    private int b;

    testing(int x,int y){
        this.a = x;
        this.b = y;
    }
}
```

Which of course for the second one would be easier to put if we do it like this:

```
public class testing {
    private int a;
    private int b;

    testing(int x,int y){
        a = x;
        b = y;
    }
}
```