# How to get the fields of Abstract class in sub class (CORE JAVA)

Tags: java, abstract-class

This is my abstract class

I can't print  fields inside abstract class from the display method in subclass

```
public abstract  class Account {
    private int cusId;
    private int cusAccountid;
    private String cusName;

    Account(int cusId, int cusAccountid,String cusName){
        this.cusId=cusId;
        this.cusName=cusName;
        this.cusAccountid=cusAccountid;             
    } 

    public int getCusId() {
        return cusId;
    }

    public int getCusAccountid() {
        return cusAccountid;
    }

    public String getCusName() {
        return cusName;
    }

    abstract public void display();    
}
```

I  just extend this abstract class(account) from (Savings class)

```
public class Savings extends Account{
    private int savId;
    private String  savBranch; 

    Savings(int cusId, int cusAccountid,String cusName,int savId, String savBranch) {
        super(cusId,cusAccountid,cusName);
        this.savId= savId;
        this.savBranch=savBranch;
       }

    @Override
    public void display() {
        Account s = null;
        System.out.println(s.getCusId()+s.getCusAccountid()+s.getCusName()+savId+savBranch);        
    }                
}
```

And here is my MAIN

```
public class Bank {

    public static void main(String[] arg){

        Savings sc = new Savings(2,2,"ram",4,"thambaram");
        sc.display();
    }

}
```

and it shows Runtime error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous tree type: <any>
    at com.trying.Savings.display(Savings.java:22)
    at com.trying.Bank.main(Bank.java:14)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)
```

Comment: Aside from anything else, it's best if you don't *try* to run code that doesn't compile. When the IDE warns you (as I'm pretty sure it would) that your code doesn't compile, and asks you if you're *sure* you want to run it anyway, say *no* and fix the compilation errors.

Comment: You can't access fields of a `null` reference either.

Comment: The code compiles fine. What are you talking about? It's all about the null reference..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the display method from the savings class to be like this (you can access it as the modifiers are public):

```
@Override
public void display() {

    System.out.println(this.getCusId()+" "+this.getCusAccountid()+" "+this.getCusName()+" "+savId+savBranch);

}
```

You were creating a null Account object and trying to display its fields which is not correct.

Comment: You should add an explanation on why ir does not work with his code but works with yours, otherwise your answer will be a copy-paste fix for him

Comment: Hey dude its working now thanks a lot.. explain me please

Comment: Hello. I simply removed Account s = null; Because of that you would have had a null object always. Like saying s=new S(2); s.display() and in the display method always making it null. Also you can remove this if you want (it will work regardless).

Comment: like: System.out.println(getCusId()+" "+getCusAccountid()+" "+getCusName()+" "+savId+savBranch);

Comment: about the "this" keyword, check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2429062/java-when-to-use-this-keyword

Answer (score 2):

By doing a quick search of your *exact* error, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333285/java-lang-runtimeexception-uncompilable-source-code-what-can-cause-this) which suggests that it's a bug in Netbeans.

If you're using Netbeans, go to `Build -> Compiling` and uncheck `Compile on save`. [Source](http://forums.netbeans.org/post-45324.html).

Oh and also, you should probably not be setting `Account s = null;` and then trying to print values from it.

Comment: It's likely not a bug in NetBeans, but rather 99.99% of the time, it's a bug in his code that he needs to fix.

Comment: Feel free to write an answer then.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem lies with the code :

```
Account s = null;
```

in the method `display` of the class `Savings`.

I feel that your main objective is to printout the values of the super class `Account` fields `cusId`, `cusAccountid`, `cusName;`. If this is correct this can be achieved by calling the public getters you have declared in the `Account` class. But if you want to access the fields of the current instance, then you should be using `this` instead of instantiating the new variable `s`. So instead of using `s.getCusId()` use `this.getCusId()` and so on.