# Java toString Method (objects)

Tags: java, string, object

```
class Position {

    private double x,y;
    private int id;

    public String toString(Position a){

        String words ="(" + a.x + "," +a.y + ")";
        return words;
```

So I'm getting a memory address returned here. What am I doing wrong? I want to get the actual values of x and y that were set using setters. I also have getters, and I tried instead of putting a.x putting getX(), but that still give me another memory address. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
public String toString(){
```

The code you have is adding a new method, instead of overriding the existing parameterless `toString` method of `Object`. That means the old method is still the one being called, and it gives the output you're seeing.

Comment: Ok that did the trick, but I'm still not understanding why it does not take any parameters?

Comment: `Object.toString()` does not take any parameters, therefore the method you write to override it must not. Consider this: `public String toString(Position a){ return "(" + a.x + "," +a.y + ")"; }  public String toString(){ return toString(this); }`

Comment: @fprime: the function is a method of the `Position` class. When you call a method, `this` points to the instance you call the function on. If you have e.g. `Position p = new Position(); p.toString();` the `toString` method acts on `p` - so no need to pass it a Position instance.

Comment: More than just the name, a method's type of params, # of params, order, etc are all part of it's signature http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html

Answer (score 3):

You're not actually overriding `toString`; rather, you're overloading it by defining a method with the same name but which expects different arguments. You don't pass a `Position` to `toString`; it should refer the current instance.

Answer (score 2):

As a complement to other posts, why do you think you need to pass `Position`'s reference to the method `toString()`, anyway. After all, the method exist in the same class, `Position`. You can use the variable/properties directly without any reference like this.

```
  public String toString(){
        return "(" + x + "," + y + ")";
  }
```

Or in case you like to specifically have a reference then you can do it like this,

```
  public String toString(){
        return "(" + this.x + "," + this.y + ")";
  }
```

I made the method one liner after refactoring.

In case you are interested in knowing which version folks like more, please refer to [here, when to use `this`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2411270/when-should-i-use-this-in-a-class). And here is the tutorial/explanation on [how overriding works in Java](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html).

Answer (score 0):

Since it is a homework, I would ask you step through a debugger. Your method is not called even though you expect it do so. ( toString()  and toString(Someobject ) are different.