# Java: Referring to the object before the dot operator in a method

Tags: java, methods, reference, dot-operator

So, here is the issue. I made a Time class which allows me to create time objects. In my time class, I created a method called `minutesUntil`. `minutesUntil` tells me the difference in minutes between two times.

To call `minutesUntil`, I used this line.

```
time1.minutesUntil(time2)
```

This is the code in `minutesUntil`.

```
 public int minutesUntil(Time other){
    int otherTotalMinutes = other.getMinutes() + (other.getHours() * 60);
    int thisTotalMinutes = ??.getMinutes() + (??.getHours() * 60);
    return (otherTotalMinutes - thisTotalMinutes);
}
```

What do I use in place of the question marks on the third line to refer to the time1 object inside of the `minutesUntil` method.

Comment: Inside instance methods (and constructors), you have a reference to the current instance in the form of the keyword `this`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [When should I use "this" in a class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2411270/when-should-i-use-this-in-a-class)

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you correctly, you want `this`; that is

```
int thisTotalMinutes = ??.getMinutes() + (??.getHours() * 60);
```

should be

```
int thisTotalMinutes = this.getMinutes() + (this.getHours() * 60);
```

Which might also be expressed like

```
// Using "this" implicitly.
int thisTotalMinutes = getMinutes() + (getHours() * 60);
```

Comment: Thanks. I thought I was supposed to use 'this.' , but I didn't get the correct value when I ran the program using 'this.', so I assumed my use of 'this.' was incorrect. After trying again, it worked. I assume I made some stupid mistake. Thank You. :)

Comment: @Underdisc You might need to check which one has a greater value before performing the subtraction.

Comment: That was the first thing I checked and it is working exactly as intended now. Thanks again. :)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need anything there. Get rid of the dots. Change this:

```
int thisTotalMinutes = ??.getMinutes() + (??.getHours() * 60);
```

to this:

```
int thisTotalMinutes = getMinutes() + (getHours() * 60);
```

Or use `this` if you desire, but I see no need to clutter the code with `this` in `this` situation.