# meaning of term THIS in generic class method?

Tags: java

In definition of generic Class `add()` method(shown below code) ,what is `this.t` doing. i mean what is " `this` " term here ? we didn't define any constructor name called `this` anywhere right ? is this predefined object ?

```
public  class Box<T> {
    private T t;

    public void add(T t) {
        this.t = t; // what is " this " term here ?
    }

    public T get() {
        return t;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Box<Integer> integerBox = new Box<Integer>();
        Box<String> stringBox = new Box<String>();

        integerBox.add(new Integer(10));
        stringBox.add(new String("Hello World"));

        System.out.printf("Integer Value :%d\n\n", integerBox.get());
        System.out.printf("String Value :%s\n", stringBox.get());
    }
}
```

Comment: There are `this` constructors, but it refers to the current `Box` instance here.

Comment: `this` refeers to the instance of the object, and since the parameter is `t`, and the property of the class is also `t`, using `this` you can differenciate which is which

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2411270/when-should-i-use-this-in-a-class

Answer (score 1):

```
public  class Box<T> {
    private T t;

    public void add(T t) {
        this.t = t; // what is " this " term here ?
    }
```

The `this.t` is refering to the current Box instance(whitch is the actual private variable). Basically thats a setter. You can read more about setters [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjbbp.html). Hope this helped!