# How to resolve SharedPreference error in android?

Tags: android

I have an app in which I am storing some values in shared preference but when I inspect code then it give

> SharedPreferences.edit() without a corresponding commit() or apply()
>   call.

How to resolve this warning.

For Shared preference I am using code mentioned below:-

```
private SharedPreferences m_Preference;
private SharedPreferences.Editor m_Editor;

m_Preference = context.getSharedPreferences(CStaticVar.DEAL_DOWNLOADED,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
m_Editor = m_Preference.edit();
                    m_Editor.putInt("dealDonloadedcount",0);
                    m_Editor.apply();
```

Comment: which android version are you using? the alert you posted is an error or an alert?

Comment: @Rakesh looks like chaining stopped working. You can split it to declaration of editor; adding values; applying the changes - 3 lines.

Answer (score 0):

In order to make changes to shared preferences you need to call

```
commit()
```

method.

Example(from Android official documentation)

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putInt(getString(R.string.saved_high_score), newHighScore);
editor.commit();
```

More in Android official documentation: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html

Comment: but I am using apply()

Comment: @Rakesh mybe this is only warning from Lint ? Did you tried to refresh project and clean Lint errors and build it again ?

Comment: as `commit()` method takes time to make changes, you can use `apply()` for making an instant save for **Shared Preferences**.

Comment: just for a note, apply more than instant is in background. it immediatly saves and it commit to disk in background

Answer (score 0):

Create a class PreferencesHelper.java

```
public class PreferencesHelper {

    private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

    public PreferencesHelper(Context context) {
        this.sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("MyPreference", 0);
        this.editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    }

    public String GetPreferences(String key) {
        return sharedPreferences.getString(key, "");
    }

    public void SavePreferences(String key, String value) {
        editor.putString(key, value);
        editor.commit();
    }
}
```

Then you can use the below code in your activity

```
PreferencesHelper pref = new PreferencesHelper(YourActivity.this);
//To Save Preferences
pref.SavePreferences("key",value);
//To Get Preferences
pref.GetPreferences("key");
```

Comment: and what about if want to store int value and get int value

Comment: @Rakesh pref.SavePreferences("key", String.valueOf(int value));

Answer (score 0):

I created the *PreferencesHelper* class proposed by [Mridul S Kumar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4818247/mridul-s-kumar) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39788031/706520) but, for some reason, the warning was still showing up. To ignore the message with `@SuppressLint("CommitPrefEdits")` was my last resort. That's why I dug a little deeper and I tried the approach mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42093111/706520) and found out that the message was gone.

So I realized that the solution is to call the **apply()** method inside the method where the editor instance variable is initialized, without using "**this**" (I don't recommend you use **commit()** because then Android will advise you, with *another warning*, to consider using *apply()* instead, on the grounds that "*commit writes its data to persistent storage, whereas apply will handle it in the background*").

I'm not sure why, but what I do know is that there is no need to use it in this case, according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2411283/706520). The variable *editor* is not a reference to be disambiguated.

Therefore, the following code should solve your problem:

```
public class PreferencesHelper {
      private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
      private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

      public PreferencesHelper(Context context) {
           this.sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("MyPreference", 0);
           this.editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

           boolean firstTime = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("first", true);
           if (firstTime) {
               editor.putBoolean("first", false);
               editor.apply();
           }
      }

      public String GetPreferences(String key) {
           return sharedPreferences.getString(key, "");
      }

      public void SavePreferences(String key, String value) {
           editor.putString(key, value);
           editor.commit();
      }
   }
}
```

I'm using **Android 3.1.4**, by the way.

Answer (score -1):

because if you change in Shared Preference the You should commit() or apply().
otherwise no meaning of this. for removing warning click on yellow mark on that particular line and disable inspection.

Comment: I didn't understand what you are trying to explain

Comment: it looks like accidently

Answer (score -1):

use

```
editor.commit();
```

in place of

```
 editor.apply();
```