# SharedPreferences.edit() without a corresponding commit() or apply() call

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I'm using SharedPreferences for my apps' Intro Slider. However, I'm getting an error on this line:

```
class PrefManager {
    private SharedPreferences pref;
    private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;


    private static final String PREF_NAME = "welcome";

    private static final String IS_FIRST_TIME_LAUNCH = "IsFirstTimeLaunch";

    PrefManager(Context context) {
        int PRIVATE_MODE = 0;
        pref = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE);
        editor = pref.edit();
    }

    void setFirstTimeLaunch(boolean isFirstTime) {
        editor.putBoolean(IS_FIRST_TIME_LAUNCH, isFirstTime);
        editor.commit();
    }

    boolean isFirstTimeLaunch() {
        return pref.getBoolean(IS_FIRST_TIME_LAUNCH, true);
    }

}
```

> editor = pref.edit();

What happens if I don't call commit() or apply() after calling edit()?

Comment: All changes you make in an editor are batched, and not copied back to the original SharedPreferences until you call commit() or apply()  From the docs at: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you do not call commit() or apply(), your changes will not be saved.

- Commit() writes the changes synchronously and directly to the file
- Apply() writes the changes to the in-memory SharedPreferences
  immediately but begins an asynchronous commit to disk

Comment: Yeah, but seems like it's working like this too, I mean I don't get intro slider again after I relaunch my app?

Comment: It looks like you are committing your changes in setFirstTimeLaunch(boolean isFirstTime).

Answer (score 5):

You can add  `@SuppressLint("CommitPrefEdits")` to ignore this message. In my case I am using it, because I want to use the same `editor` field in my class.

```
public class ProfileManager {

    private SharedPreferences preferences;
    private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

    @SuppressLint("CommitPrefEdits")
    @Inject
    ProfileManager(SharedPreferences preferences) {
        this.preferences = preferences;
        this.editor = preferences.edit();
    }

    public void setAccountID(int accountID) {
        editor.putInt(AppConstants.ACCOUNT_ID_KEY, accountID)
                .apply();
    }

    public int getAccountID() {
        return preferences.getInt(AppConstants.ACCOUNT_ID_KEY, AppConstants.INVALID_ACCOUNT_ID);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

> What happens if I don't call commit() or apply() after calling edit()?

Nothing.

Answer (score 4):

**Simple Method**

```
 sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("ShaPreferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                boolean firstTime = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("first", true);
                if (firstTime) {
                    editor.putBoolean("first", false);
                    //For commit the changes, Use either editor.commit(); or  editor.apply();.
                    editor.commit();
                    Intent i = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, StartUpActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    finish();
                } else {
                        Intent i = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
                        startActivity(i);
                        finish();
                }
                    }
```