# What is the purpose of the `obj` argument in `synchronized(obj) {...}`?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety

What is the difference between this two?

```
public void someMethod(){

     synchronized(this){
      //some code

      }
}
```

and

```
public void someMethod(){

   Object lock = new Object();
   synchronized(lock){
   //some code

    }
```

}

*Also please make me clear, If I mention an object inside the Synchronize parenthesis, is that mean, I will be able to use thread safe for that particular object?*

Comment: The second is pointless. You synchronize code to control repeated invoking by different threads. Creating a new lock to sync on each time is like *not synchronizing* at all.

Comment: synchronization deals with Sharing of a critical section (statements) of code within multiple Threads such that one thread executes it at a time. Local variable `lock` gets initialized each time the method is being invoked. Now each thread will create a different object and hence it will **not be shared**. Now whatever critical statements you have within synchronized block will be guarded by different lock objects. You have multiple threads working on same *critical section* at same time and synchronization although applied is not effective at all.

Comment: `this` is shared by all the instance methods. It is not something which is local to a method. Hence synchronization works. Multiple threads will access critical section of code guarded by synchronized block on `this` will enter critical section at a time as `this` is shared by all the threads entering an instance method

Comment: The answers on the "duplicate" don't answer this question. The other question was answered by explaining what `this` means. But, what we have here is a question about what `synchronized` means.

Comment: No, `synchronized(obj)` does _not_ protect `obj` from access by other threads. The main thing it does is, it stops other threads from entering any block of code that is synchronized on the same object. You can use that feature to protect `obj` or, you can use it to protect any _other_ variables. But, it's up to you to ensure that the variable (or variables) that you want to protect are only ever accessed from inside `synchronized` blocks that all synchronize on the same object.

Answer (score 3):

When using synchronized keyword, you need an object as monitor lock. Only threads using the same monitor lock will be synchronized.

- `synchronized(this)` synchronized on current instance. Check  [`this`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2411270/when-should-i-use-this-in-a-class) keyword in Java.

  - When calling `someMethod` on the same instance from different threads, these threads will be synchronized.
  - When calling `someMethod` on the different instances from different threads, these threads will not be synchronized.
- The second version does not have any synchronization function, since every thread has their own method stack, and they will create their own `Object lock` on their method stack.

Comment: But I am getting some different result.

Comment: @AmartyaKaran, Synchronization-related bugs are notoriously difficult to find and reproduce. I have analyzed crash dumps from customer sites, and found bugs in a large, multi-threaded software system that passed all of its tests and ran for the equivalent of several years in the field before the bug revealed itself.

Answer (score 1):

Before we get into the differences, let's first try and understand what is `this` keyword in JAVA. An instance of a class can refer to itself using `this`. One can use `this` keyword to access class members as well (only non-static ones).

Now synchronization in JAVA is based on `Objects`, where each `Object` maintains a monitor which allows only one thread to access `synchronized` code block (or `synchronized` method). Therefore, it is important that **same** object is shared across different threads in order for them to synchronize correctly.

First version above ensures correct synchronization when same instance of that class is shared across multiple threads.

The second version is basically creating a `new Object` every time `someMethod` is called, which means even if the same instance of that class was shared across multiple threads, each of those threads would synchronize on **different** copy of `lock` object, thus effectively leading to no synchronization.

To make things a little more clear, here are some other variants of first version.

```
public void someMethod() {
 // Note that assignment below is redundant and is shown for example purposes.
 Object lock = this;
 synchronized(lock){
    //some code
  }
}

public synchronized void someMethod() {
 //some code
}
```

As for which version should one select. This totally depends on what method does.

If all operations performed by method requires synchronization, then I prefer to use `synchronized` method  (last option). This prevents an extra indentation and is slightly more readable. Otherwise, first variant makes sense where you can perform operations that do not require synchronization outside `synchronized` block.

Comment: But I am getting some different result.
I have a Demothread class

public class Demothread {
   
   void  display(){
   for(int j=0;j<200;j++){System.out.println(j);}
   }
}

I have created two Thread. Made an object reference of Demothread class. 

Now I am calling 
# Thread 1 # calling display() within a synchronized block of demoted object
# Thread 2 # calling display() without synchronized block . What will be result?

Comment: Without looking at your code, it is unclear what you are trying to do.

Comment: Re, "...effectively leading to incorrect synchronizaion." I would have said, "effectively _no_ synchronization."

Comment: SGTM. Thanks for the suggestion.