# Calling non static method without class instance inside a non static method

Tags: java, methods, static, class-method, non-static

```
class GFG {
public static void main (String[] args) {
    GFG g=new GFG();
    g.pri();

}

void pri(){    
  mod();
}
void mod()
{
    System.out.println("HHI");
}

}
```

In this following code when i am calling a  mod() method inside a non static method without creating class instance for mod() method it does work and given Output "Hi";
According to the definition of non static method cannot be called without Class instance;

How it does work?

Comment: `new GFG()` does create an instance. So what are you actually asking?

Comment: Four letters - `this`

Comment: There has to be a dupetarget for this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [*When should I use “this” in a class?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2411270/when-should-i-use-this-in-a-class)

Comment: In order for pri() to be called you must of had an instance (created with the "new" keyword in your main).  Once pri() is executing, you **ARE IN THAT INSTANCE**...and calling mod() runs it in the same instance that you are in.  Thus the "this" keyword, which means find the thing inside the currently running instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has an instance, the one you created in `main`, which you used when doing `g.pri()`. Within an instance method like `pri`, the instance it was called on is available as `this`, and `this.` is optional. In an instance method, these two statements do **exactly** the same thing:

```
mod();
this.mod();
```

If you don't include the `this.`, the Java compiler adds it for you.

*(As a matter of **opinion**, I suggest you include it, at the very least for fields, since otherwise in the code `x = y + 1` you have no idea whether `x` and `y` are locals in the method or fields on the instance.)*

Answer (score 0):

```
class GFG {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        GFG g=new GFG();
        g.pri();
    }
}
```

It works, because you call non-static pri() method of instance of GFC.

```
class GFG {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        pri();
    }
}
```

will fails, because you call non-static pri() from static main()