# Sorting an object of an object

Tags: java, sorting, java-stream, comparator

I want to use the stream api sorting with a Comparator parameter but it doesn't sort properly. I always get exception.

I want to sort an object with a reference to another object, and the referenced object has a String so I want to sort it to its length.

This is my main method.

```
List<Person> liste = Arrays.asList(new Person(new Info("akin"))
                                  ,new Person(new Info("lars"))
                                  ,new Person(new Info("aaa")));

liste.stream()
     .map(p -> p.f)
     .map(f -> f.name)
     .sorted((s,s2) -> s.length() - s2.length())
     .forEach(System.out::print);
```

Comment: What kind of exception do you get?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at MainStart.lambda$main$0(MainStart.java:43)
     …..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: is it because it is an optional method?

Comment: @bratan without the complete details of the actual code that you're executing with, it's tough to say why it would result in a `NullPointerException`. Though you've got to still check the values of `person`, `info` and `name` for each object should not be `null`, that is where the exception could arise from.

Comment: yeah i tried it with integer and it works but with string it dont work, dont know why

Answer (score 1):

I'll make an assumption here because your stream code looks good.

I assume that in at least one of the two constructors (either for `Person` or for `Info`) you didn't assign the incoming value properly to the instance field, hence it is null and trying to get `f.name` or `[f.name].length()` will lead to a NullPointerException.

Below is a working example of the stream that you posted (you will notice, I did not change anything in the code in your question except for some indentation).

```java
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Person> liste = Arrays.asList(new Person(new Info("akin")),
                new Person(new Info("lars")),
                new Person(new Info("aaa")));

        liste.stream()
                .map(p -> p.f)
                .map(f -> f.name)
                .sorted((s, s2) -> s.length() - s2.length())
                .forEach(System.out::print);
    }

    static class Person {
        Info f;

        public Person(Info f) {
            this.f = f;
        }
    }

    static class Info {
        String name;

        public Info(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
    }

}
```

Your constructor might look like

```java
public Person(Info f) {
    f = f;
}
```

(notice the missing `this` compared to my example). [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2411283/11806939) is a good read on uses of `this`.

My IDE also suggested a minor change on the `sorted` method. You can use [Comparator#comparingInt](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparingInt-java.util.function.ToIntFunction-) which would look like this:

```java
.sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(String::length))
```

This really comes down to what you think is more readable though.

For further reference on NullPointerExceptions please read the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it) that was already posted in the comments. This won't have been your last one ;)