# Is it good practice to include the this keyword in a class method?

Tags: java, object

For example I have a method which displays the information about the instance of Employee

```
//Displaying the instance of the object information in a anesthetically pleasing manner
public void display() {
    System.out.println("Employee Information");
    seperationLine();
    System.out.println("Name: " + getName());
    seperationLine();
    System.out.println("PPS number: " + getPpsNum());
    seperationLine();
    System.out.println("Salary: " + getSalary());

}
```

Should I use the `this`keyword in the method and other methods which need to use a attribute or is it not necessary

```
//Displaying the instance of the object information in a anesthetically pleasing manner
public void display() {
    System.out.println("Employee Information");
    seperationLine();
    System.out.println("Name: " + this.getName());
    seperationLine();
    System.out.println("PPS number: " + this.getPpsNum());
    seperationLine();
    System.out.println("Salary: " + this.getSalary());

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When should I use "this" in a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2411270/when-should-i-use-this-in-a-class)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is really more of a style question.

In earlier days, editors weren't smart enough to understand: those are fields of the class, so they could/should be highlighted in a different color (compared to local variables).

But nowadays even small editors understand such things. Therefore you don't gain much from using `this` in places where it is not required to be used. So, I recommend: only write down `this` when you [have to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2411270/when-should-i-use-this-in-a-class).

Beyond that, the real issue here: don't write such `display()` methods. The real world practice: @Override the `toString()` method, and have that return a *meaningful* representation of your class.

Then whenever you intend to log or display an instance of your class, you call `employee.toString()` ... and you use the returned string the way you like it.

Meaning: it is a really bad idea to *display* to the console. What if you want to log stuff into a file later on for example?!

Answer (score 0):

So long as 'this' is an instance of that particular class, it's still a good practice to embrace. Otherwise you have to initially declare an object in order to apply the methods. You can also use new ClassName().method() on the go. All the best!

Answer (score 0):

In the specific code you posted, it's not necessary to use the `this` keyword. However, you must use the `this` keyword if you have two conflicting names in your context and you want to reference the class member, because `this` returns a reference to the current object. For instance, assume you have

```
class Employee
{
    int age;
    int _salary;

    public void setAge(int age)
    {
        this.age = age; //You need this.age in order to differentiate it from the int age parameter of the method.
    }

    public void setSalary(int salary)
    {
        _salary = salary; //No need for this._salary, it's redundant since names don't conflict with each other.
    }
}
```

As for whether it is good practice or not, it really depends on what's considered *good practice* for you or for your employer, or according to a coding standard guideline you could been abiding by, either personally or at your work.