# I'm not really getting the constructor methods

Tags: this

```
public class LinkedListNode {
    public LinkedListNode next;
    public LinkedListNode prev;
    public LinkedListNode last;
    public int data;
    public LinkedListNode(int d, LinkedListNode n, LinkedListNode p) {
        data = d;
        setNext(n);
        setPrevious(p);
    }
    
    public LinkedListNode(int d) {
        data = d;
    }   
    
    public LinkedListNode() { }

    public void setNext(LinkedListNode n) {
        next = n;
        if (this == last) {
            last = n;
        }
        if (n != null && n.prev != this) {
            n.setPrevious(this);
        }
    }       
    public void setPrevious(LinkedListNode p) {
        prev = p;
        if (p != null && p.next != this) {
            p.setNext(this);
        }
    }
```

- How did `setNext` and `setPrevious` work in this class?
- What does a single "this" refer to in those cases?
- And what was that if statement for?

Comment: `this` refers to the instance you are presently in.  So it is checking to see if for example, `p.next` is not the same instance via `p.next != this`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When should I use "this" in a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2411270/when-should-i-use-this-in-a-class)

Answer (score 0):

`this` refers to an object it is inside of. You can only use `this` inside of the class, for example `this.next` is the same as `next` inside of this class code. Consequently `this` is the object itself.

Answer (score 0):

`this` is a constant variable that points to the current class, so it basically refers to `public class LinkedListNode` in a way. The `setNext` method sets the `next` variable to `n`, then checks if the current class is the same class as the `last` variable, finally it checks if `n` isn't null and the `prev` variable of the `n` class isn't the current class, then calling `setPrevious` in the `n` class.

`setPrevious` sets the `prev` variable to `p` which would be the previous occurance of `this` which is now `p` in the `n` class, and then if the previous class reference isn't null and the `next` variable of the previous class reference isn't the now current class reference which was `this`, it calls `setNext`.

Answer (score 0):

`this` refers to the instance you are presently in. So it is checking to see if for example, `p.next` is not the same instance via `p.next != this`

Here is an example to demonstrate the concept.

```
Foo foo1 = new Foo();
Foo foo2 = new Foo();
System.out.println(foo1);
foo1.printInstance(foo1); // should be the same.
System.out.println(foo2);
foo1.printInstance(foo2);

public class Foo {
   public void printInstance(Foo foo) {
        System.out.println(this);
        System.out.println(this == foo ? "Equal" : "Not equal");
    } 
}
```

Prints something similar to the following:

```
Foo@7a81197d
Foo@7a81197d
Equal
Foo@5ca881b5
Foo@7a81197d
Not equal
```