# Difference between the code with "this" and without it

Tags: java

I'm a beginner in Java programming and I'm having some problems to understand some concepts. I would like to know if both implementations are the same:

**Code 1**

```
public class MyThisTest {
  private int a;

  public MyThisTest(int a) {
    this.a = a;
  }
```

**Code 2**

```
public class MyThisTest {
  private int a;

  public MyThisTest(int b) {
    a = b;
  }
```

Comment: Yes, both are the same.

Comment: The primary use of `this` is to disambiguate variable references. See [when to use this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2411270/when-should-i-use-this-in-a-class).

Comment: @jarmod That's exactly what I wanted to know. Thank you!

Comment: @jarmod a _secondary_ use of `this` is when you're a beginner and want the IDE to help you with `Ctrl` + `Space` (or am I the only one who did this...)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, both are the same, let's see why:

First

```java
public class MyThisTest {
  private int a;

  public MyThisTest(int a) {
    this.a = a;
  }
```

You are using `this` to refer the member variable `a`. The use of `this` is because by parameter there is another `a` variable. If you don't use `this` what variable will be assigned the value? The same as the parameter, so it doesn't take effect because it is 'auto-assign' the value.

Word `this` ensures tthe member variable is referenced. This is mostly used in constructors and getter/setters because the parameter name should be the same as the member variable name, so to handle the ambiguity `this` is used.

The second code

```java
public class MyThisTest {
  private int a;

  public MyThisTest(int b) {
    a = b;
  }
```

Into constructor there is no ambiguity between variables, so `this` is not needed, but you can still use `this` and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Yes both implementations are same. But I would highly recommend you to read about it in detail so that you don't make any future mistake. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2411270/when-should-i-use-this-in-a-class) answer goes in detail about when we should use `this`.

Answer (score 1):

this keyword would be added by compiler.
Actually, if you write something like this

```
public class A {

    private int a;

    public A(int b) {
        a = b;
    }
}
```

Compile and then decompile it you can see the work of compiler

```
 //
// Source code recreated from a .class file by IntelliJ IDEA
// (powered by FernFlower decompiler)
//


public class A {
    private int a;

    public A(int b) {
        this.a = b;
    }
}
```

So, i would say avoiding this is just a usage of some syntax sugar.