# What does it mean when: { props } = this

Tags: reactjs

I have seen { props } = this, within the following piece of code. What is this used?

```
render = () => {
        const { props } = this
```

Comment: Object destructuring: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#object_destructuring

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When should I use "this" in a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2411270/when-should-i-use-this-in-a-class)

Answer (score 3):

This is not a feature of React. This is the destructuring syntax of JS. Any object which looks like the following :-

`let obj = {name:'Arjunan'}`

can be destructured to access `name` property like :-

`const {name} = obj`

In your question, `this` is the object created using your React class constructor and the property `props` exist on it.